# Manifolds Definition

Tags: manifolds, tensors

I have encountered the following definition of a manifold:
A manifold $M$ is a space satisfying the following properties.

1- There exists a family of open neighborhoods $U_i$ together with continuous one-to-one mappings $f_i:U_i\rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$ with a continuous inverse for a number n.

2- The family of open neighborhoods covers the whole of $M$; i.e.

$\bigcup_iU_i=M$

But doesn't that mean the maps are bijections since they have inverses? If so, why didn't write that instead of one-to-one?
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item 1 is badly worded in a couple of ways, one of which is what you noticed. What I particularly notice is that the item 1 does not say whether $f_i$ needs to be surjective.

If the intention is that $f_i$ need not be surjective, then to define the relevant inverse map one should first specify the image $V_i = f_i(U_i) \subset \mathbb R^n$, and then say that $f_i^{-1} : V_i \to U_i$ is continuous. But if that was indeed the intention then there's something missing: one must also specify that $V_i$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

If the intention is that $f_i$ is indeed surjective, then it would be nice if it said so.

I'll say that either of the above two alternatives is acceptable: they yield two equivalent definitions of a manifold, because of the fact that every open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

As for why the definition is poorly written in this fashion, I cannot help you. I would suggest asking the author/instructor/person-who-wrote-it, if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was quite helpful. I knew that he was trying to say that each of these neighborhoods is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^n$, and this is why I was confused by the way he formulated item 1. Everything is clear now, thanks :)

Comment: By the way, in case you had not noticed, when you have a satisfactory answer you can "accept" it by clicking on the accept button. This provides reputation points to answerers, and is an important motivation that keeps the site going.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know that!